# Language Design: Combining Gotos and Functions

Tags: function, language-design, interpreter, goto

I'm designing and currently rethinking a low-level interpreted programming language with similarities to assembler.

I very soon came across the functions/loops/gotos decision problem and thought that while loops like `while` and `for` would be too high-level and unfitting, gotos would be too low level, unmaintainable and generally evil again.
Functions like you know them from most languages that have return values and arguments aren't fitting in the language's concept either.

So I tried to figure out something between a function and a goto which is capable of

- Recursion
- Efficient loops

After some thinking I came up with the idea of subroutines:

- They have a beginning and an end like a function
- They have a name but no arguments like a goto
- You can go into one with jump and go out of it again before its end with `return` (doesn't give back  any result, only stops the subroutine)
- Handled just like normal code -> Global scope like goto

So I wanted to know:

- Is the idea above good? What are the (dis)advantages?
- Would there be a better combination of function and goto or even a completely new idea?

Comment: So you're basically implementing GOSUB?

Comment: You mean that thing from BASIC? Possible, yet I don't know if GOSUB supports recursion.

Comment: If your subroutine does not have parameters or variables, the question about recursion is irrelevant.

Comment: @PauliL: What you are saying is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the idea above good?

No.

Or at least not until you give a much better explanation of **what problems you are trying solve** by designing a new language.

> What are the (dis)advantages?

No functional abstraction, no recursion, programming only by sharing mutable state.  Very weak composition principle.  Difficult to use for a human programmer and having no point as a compiler target.

---

To get somewhere with a project like this, you have to have a goal.  If your goal is to learn something, you're better off studying some great languages and trying to figure what you can steal, what you can combine, or what you can implement.  If you have a real problem you're trying to solve, and it can't be solved by a standard assembly language, that's interesting—tell us what it is.

You might try Googling "portable assembly language" and see if you hit anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you're at assembly-level, GOTO stops being evil, and starts just being how programs actually *work*.

But anyway, do your sub-routines take parameters? Even if they don't, how do your store register state to avoid recursion overflow?

Comment: I use a stack with the positions of the jumps so the interpreter knows where to return to after a subroutine. However, to avoid memory-eating, slowiness and overflow the stack isn't used when a subroutine calls itself -> loop.

Comment: Sub, if you do not store the return address when a subroutine calls itself, it is not really recursion. And there is no point to implement loop by using "recursion". Use goto instead.

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine you are implementing is just the same as **GOSUB** in Basic or **CALL** in Assembly.

Recursion is only meaningful if you are using it for recursive algorithms. That requires functions with parameters, local variables and a return-value.

However, in some simple scripting languages that only have global variables, there are **PUSH** and **POP** instructions for storing variables in stack (just like registers are pushed and popped in Assembly language). Those can be used for low-level implementation of local variables and recursion.

I have used that method in some Vedit Macro Language examples in Rosetta Code, see for example [Towers of Hanoi](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Towers_of_Hanoi#Vedit_macro_language) and [Bezier curve](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/B%C3%A9zier_curves/Quadratic#Vedit_macro_language).